# What is the core of the cubic 3-fold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact, smooth, $1$-connected, orientable $6$-manifold with torsion free homology, then (from Wall's classification) $X$ has a (smooth) connect sum decomposition $X \cong X_{0} \#_{k} S^{3} \times S^3$ (i.e. the connect sum of $X_{0}$ with k copies of $S^{3} \times S^{3}$), where $b_{3}(X_{0}) = 0$ and $2k = b_{3}(X)$.

We refer to $X_{0}$ as the core of $X$ (following section 5 of "Cubic forms and Complex 3-folds" by Okonek and van de Ven).

**Question**: How to compute the core $X_{0}$ of a smooth cubic hypersurface $X \subset \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^{4}$, so that $X \cong X_{0} \#_{5} S^3 \times S^3$?

Is there a general method to find the core of a smooth projective $3$-fold (over $\mathbb{C}$, with $b_{3}(X) \neq 0$ and trivial $\pi_{1}$)?

Comment: Do you have a link to the Okonek--Van de Ven article? I cannot seem to find it...

Comment: Yes, it is open access. Go the the following link https://www.zora.uzh.ch/id/eprint/22598/  , then on the right hand side there is a blue link saying "view at publisher". That takes you straight to the article.